# How to solve Error 404 when deploying laravel project to Cpanel?

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I'm trying to deploy my laravel (Laravel Framework 7.28.3) to Cpanel, but got a 404 error.
I uploaded my project into /public_html, modified the index.php file to point to the correct files (as below).
I think there must be some mistake in the index.php file but couldn't figure it out.
This is my first time asking my question (after searching for it several times), so hope that I will get the answer!

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

this is my file structure in File Manager:

[image: file structure in File Manager]

Comment: check your `.htaccess` file in public folder, if it was not there then upload it.

Comment: as per your file structure it will work `dmaiin.com/public` will be the url  you need to change your folder structure

Comment: checked, it's still inside the public folder

Comment: what si your url .? i can show you this

Comment: my url is emglabvn.com.vn,

Comment: i created test.html file inside public folder, and somehow it worked when i go to emglabvn.com.vn/test.html

Comment: do you have permission to point the root directory for a domain??

Comment: You can access with http://example.com/public ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update (2023) easy way

##### if you have access to terminal you can run this command

`ln -s /laravel/public/* public_html`

This is easy way i found in 2023

---

### Deploy laravel application in Cpanel

- **Setup 1 : -** upload file to **Cpanel**  the **root** directory – not the **public_html**.
- **Setup 2 : -** Open the that folder and MOVE the CONTENTS of the public folder to your cpanel’s **public_html** .
- **Setup 3 : -**  Navigate to the **public_html** folder and locate the `index.php` file. Right click on it and select Code Editor from the menu.

and change this line

```php
require __DIR__.'/../folderName/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../folderName/bootstrap/app.php';
```

> **NOTE** : -  **folderName** here is in root where you laravel application stay

that's it now all your request will come inside  **public_html** folder `index.php` and this file will include `require __DIR__.'/../folderName/vendor/autoload.php;` and run laravel application

---

### Folder structure will look like

```
/laravel
/public_html/index.php
```

indside `index.php`

```php
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';;
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php'; // here laravel is folder name
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222978/discussion-on-answer-by-kamlesh-paul-how-to-solve-error-404-when-deploying-larav).

Answer (score 3):

In your public/.htaccess file replaces the code given below..make sure that you uploaded your project in the root public_html folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

Comment: provide detailed solution for problem, so other user can understand what going on in each line or why we use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your application is in a folder outside of your public_html.

Then you need to make a symbolic link to everything in your public directory inside your application. This symbolic link should be placed in your public_html.

This way your business logic is not available from the outside, only from your own application.

Actually it is advisable to clone your application using git and then install it following the steps in de docs. (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation)