# Laravel make routing to subfolder on deploy

Tags: php, laravel, web, server

I have a Laravel Apps and a shared hosting. I wanted to deploy my Laravel apps to cpanel, and got an error

`404 resources not found` when deployed. I have put the laravel public folder into the root folder, and the laravel file into subfolder `/laravelApp`.

So my hosting structured like this :

```
bdd.services
|--> public_html
|----> myLaravelApp
|------> css
|------> js
|------> laravelApp
|--------> app
|--------> /* and all the laravel apps inside here */
|------> .htaccess
|------> index.php
|
|
|----> someonesProject
```

When I tried to test the app, I see the request was requesting to

`https://mydoamin.com/login/auth` where it should be `https://mydoamin.com/myLaravelApp/login/auth`. And it shows an error `404 resources not found`.

So how to make the routing always go to `https://mydoamin.com/myLaravelApp/`? or maybe there's another solution?

here's my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've also set the `APP_URL` at the `.env`.

`APP_URL=https://mydoamin.com/myLaravelApp/`

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333428/how-to-solve-error-404-when-deploying-laravel-project-to-cpanel/64333726#64333726

Comment: I think there's no problem with the `index.php`. Because I've tried to change the form action to `/myLaravelApp/login/auth` and the laravel works fine. the problem is the route always goes to root folder not the subfolder

Comment: ohh then inside your code your using `<a href="/login">logn</a>` here `/` means root path

Comment: APP_URL="https://whatever.com/my-folder"

Comment: I've set the APP_URL, please kindly check my edited @DevinGray. yeah it's `<a href="/login/auth">logn</a>`. I want it to direct to `https://mydoamin.com/myLaravelApp/`

Comment: you should not do 302 redirect to main website to new it can effect your `/` root website as well , instead change the url in website   `<a href="/login/auth">logn</a>` to `<a href="{{ url('login/auth') }}">logn</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should ensure that you have

```
APP_URL="http://example.com/folder"
```

In your .env file

Then instead of doing an href like this

```
href="/login"
```

Give your route a name

```
Route::get('login', ...)->name('login');
```

and do your href like this

```
href="{{ route('login') }}"
```

This way it will always use the full url