# Deploy laravel project on subfolder in cpanel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.6 . In my cpanel I keep php version 7.1 . I want to deploy it on a subfolder like url should be **[www.domain.com/project](http://www.domain.com/project)** . I uploaded my full project in a subfolder. But I have to go **[www.domain.com/project/public](http://www.domain.com/project/public)** this url to access project , which not my expectation. And If I hit any route it creates ***[www.domain.com/route](http://www.domain.com/route)** and shows **404**. It's not taking subfolder name. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: check this it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333428/how-to-solve-error-404-when-deploying-laravel-project-to-cpanel/64333726#64333726

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve Error 404 when deploying laravel project to Cpanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333428/how-to-solve-error-404-when-deploying-laravel-project-to-cpanel)

Comment: you don't need to deploy your entire project in public_html of your hosting server. Just upload your project's public folder inside public_html and rename it as 'project' or whatever and don't forget to change path inside public/index.php which points to your project.

Comment: Thanks  Akash Sarode . But where I keep rest part of my project . I mean except public folder

Comment: I did that. but every routes it hits **www.domain.com/route** but it should be **www.domain.com/subfolder/route**

Comment: @Mithun it is depend on how your using urls in your project if u used full path inside project then `subfolder` will work or else it will redirect to `www.domain.com/route`

Comment: Thanks but if I use subdomain or main domain , then it works