# Setup Laravel 8 & voyager in Shared Hosting

Tags: laravel, web-hosting, host, shared-hosting, voyager

I've been working on a ecommerce website for the first time and used voyager for my admin panel. The website is nearly done. I want to know what are the steps to host my project with working voyager admin panel. PHP version is 7.4.11. Hoping to host this with Cloudlinux. Much appreciate if someone can teach me the steps. Thank You!

Comment: take a look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333428/how-to-solve-error-404-when-deploying-laravel-project-to-cpanel/64333726#64333726

Comment: @KamleshPaul thank you but i saw somewhere that after hosting, voyager is not going to work as it did before.

Comment: what error your getting ?