# How to fix revolution slider in my website?

Tags: laravel, revolution-slider

I am using revolution slider in my Laravel website.When i removed the "/public" from the url using a .htaccess file  in my root folder with this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

The slider is not loading correctly anymore(no slider shown)
This is the html code:

```
<div class="topslider" style="margin-top: 80px;">
    <div id="slider">
        <div class="fullwidthbanner-container">
            <div id="revolution-slider">
                <ul>
                    @foreach($sliders as $slider)
                        @if($slider->type == 'video' && $slider->video && File::exists($slider->video))
                        <li {{-- data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="5000" --}}>
                            <video poster="" id="bgvid" playsinline="" autoplay="" muted="" loop="">
                                <source src="{{ asset($slider->video)}}" alt="" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                           {{--  <video src="{{ asset($slider->video)}}" type="video/mp4" playsinline autoplay muted loop> </video>  --}}
                            
                        </li> 
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tp-bullets">
            <div class="simplebullets round bullet">
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally this my [website url](http://mandarine-digital.com/clients/mandarine)

I get this error in my console:"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextElementSibling' of null"

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using?

Comment: i am using laravel 5.4

Comment: for remove public folder use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333428/how-to-solve-error-404-when-deploying-laravel-project-to-cpanel/64333726#64333726  and keep `.htaccess` as orgianl state don't so anything   this is safer way to use in cpanel

Comment: i am not using Cpanel so i don't have a public_html folder

Answer (score 0):

The standard **.htaccess** which comes with Laravel 5.4 is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Try to replace your **.htaccess** file in `public/.htaccess` with this contents.

Content copied from https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.4/public/.htaccess

Comment: i didn't change the .htaccess inside my public folder i kept it as it is.I added a .htaccess file in my root folder to remove the  public/ from my url

Comment: The .htaccess in public folder is sufficient with the document root of the virtual host set to the project's public folder - no need for a separate .htaccess file in the root folder

Comment: this is what i did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url

Comment: That is a very insecure way of hosting Laravel application in production. Best is to point the DocumentRoot for the virtual host configuration to the **public** folder of your project. That way only the public folder is accessible. Copying the .htaccess file in the root folder and setting the DocumentRoot to the project root folder makes the application vulnerable from security point of view and is not encouraged

Comment: how can i do this "Best is to point the DocumentRoot for the virtual host configuration to the public folder of your project"

Comment: See this tutorial for how to setup virtual hosts on Apache https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart

Comment: i do not have a sudo user on your server nor an Apache2 web server,

Comment: Which webserver you are using to host the site

Comment: Is it shared hosting or vps?

Comment: <?php
print_r($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']);
?> => Apache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226129/discussion-between-youssef-boudaya-and-donkarnash).