# laravel error while uploading project on cpanel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload projects on server but I found error as  "[26-Jan-2021 16:31:26 Etc/GMT] PHP Parse error:

> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in
> /home/indextechno/public_html/demo7/vendor/symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php
> on line 23"

Comment: use this method in cpanel  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333428/how-to-solve-error-404-when-deploying-laravel-project-to-cpanel/64333726#64333726

Comment: @KamleshPaul hello can you see my cpanel structure

Comment: no you can upload that

Comment: @ i uploaded it same way on another domain it will works

Comment: @KamleshPaul but in this domain  gives error

Comment: run composer install

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227872/discussion-between-seema-patil-and-kamlesh-paul).

Comment: @KamleshPaul plz check my error

Comment: did you ran `composer install` cmd ?

Comment: @hi
it works for when index.php add in  all public folder content move in public_html folder
but i want to save in public_html/demo7/folder
then which path i a m change

Comment: @KamleshPaul are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

this error is obvious message you have some syntax error in that file.

first check code in IDE to ensure everything is fine and then upload it to host.