# Why does Laravel website runs on two different paths with the same route on the live server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, redirect

I uploaded the laravel project on the live server. When I try the url with :

```
www.abcd.com.au/admin/dashboard
```

then it shows me a messed up site and also shows some contents that were downloaded from bootstrap template website .

And when I try this url:

```
www.abcd.com.au/project/public/admin/dashboard
```

then it shows me the correct website and neatly as the way website was designed on the localhost xampp and on the live server.

I wanted to have the url as: **/admin/dashboard** and not **project/public/admin/dashboard**

How can i set up this on the live server please?

Thanks.

Comment: what server your using ?

Comment: well, its a shared server. i tried to look for the conf file but no luck

Comment: so when you add domain to particular folder add `public` folder as root

Comment: or you can use this method to deploy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333428/how-to-solve-error-404-when-deploying-laravel-project-to-cpanel/64333726#64333726

Comment: the laravel project is extracted inside public_html folder. So, public_html/project/and all the folders and files of laravel project

Comment: @KamleshPaul I tried the solution but still it doent work. I updated the lines in the index.php file, but `www.abcd.com.au/project/public/admin/dashboard` shows error (warning) and `www.abcd.com.au/admin/dashboard` this show the same issue regarding the problem i have posted.

Comment: change all the origin `server.php` and `.htaccess` then my code will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229189/discussion-between-user10345537-and-kamlesh-paul).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your URL is pointed to the wrong folder. In Laravel the URL must point to the project's public folder.

Answer (score 1):

open your VirtualHost on your server .conf file and update DocumentRoot and try

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Path your project/project/public"
    ServerName www.abcd.com.au

    <Directory "/Path your project/project/public">
      Options All
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from all

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: hi, thanks. Where do i find the conf file on the cpanel - live server?

Comment: check In /usr/local/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf