# image upload (move) does not work on laravel

Tags: laravel

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->merge(['slug' => Str::slug($request->baslik), 'user_id' => auth()->user()->id, 'hit' => 0   ]);

        
        $add = Ilan::create($request->post());

        $insertedId = $add->id;

        if($files=$request->file('images')){
            foreach($files as $file){
                $photo = new Photo;

                $name=rand(0,4000).'-'.Str::slug($request->baslik).'-'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move(public_path('uploads'),$name);
                $photo->ilan_id = $insertedId;
                $photo->url = 'uploads/'.$name;
                $photo->save();
            }
        }

        return redirect()->route('ilan.index');
    }
```

This is my function. It's working in Local. But when I try it in a server it's not working. Image is not creating and there is no error. Where is the problem, if you help me i will be glad, thank you.

My public folder is:  `sample.com/references/website`
I didnt send public folder to the main folder

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: No, there is no error

Comment: `dd($request->all());` to check file exist or not

Comment: check server permission

Comment: @sta the file exist. There is no problem. I think the problem is related with link structure but i could not solved

Comment: Please share your project structure directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you public directory named `something else`  instead of `public` inside your hosting  that is why you are facing that issue ..

[follow that link for solving the issue](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5) this link is for laravel 5

for laravel 8 [you can check that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67328616/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel-8)