# Laravel: How to configure api.php routes for shared hosting?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, axios

I have the following .htaccess fille:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

#disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes

#PROTECT ENV FILE
<Files .env>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

#PROTECT ENV FILE
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

But the problem is I get a 404 status code in my production environment when trying to load "getservicedata" from a vue.js component. I think the problem is in the URL because it works when I type in the correct url, but the problem is the app loads the API from wrong URL.

I followed this guide to setup laravel shared hosting: https://laravelarticle.com/deploy-laravel-on-shared-hosting

[image: 404 status code]

[image: 200 status using the correct url]

Comment: can you show locahost htaccess .look like localhost has estimeringapp in url so

Comment: its the same as in the production environment. The .htaccess locally is in the public folder. i have setup .htaccess and index.php in the root folder for production environment

Comment: i recommand you use like this on cpanel don't depend `.htaccess` to handel route redirect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333428/how-to-solve-error-404-when-deploying-laravel-project-to-cpanel/64333726#64333726

Comment: I just did, same issue