# Laravel storage link keep redirected to /public directory in hosting

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, laravel-storage

I'm using a hosting service to upload my laravel project and link it to laravel's public directory using php header location in laravel's root directory. Then I created a storage link in public directory using symlink or artisan command, but when I'm trying to access the files it always redirected to /public, I wonder why?

Header location index.php

```
<?php 
    header('Location: public/');
?>
```

The image link :

[image: Image link under storage directory]

But when I'm trying to view the image by clicking the image link, it always redirected to /public directory

Result Image

[image: Result Image]

Comment: you need to hide `public` from your url

Comment: @KamleshPaul how can I do that?

Comment: deploy like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333428/how-to-solve-error-404-when-deploying-laravel-project-to-cpanel/64333726#64333726

Comment: becouse anyone can get your `.env` file like this https://pusakamu.com/.env

Comment: You should set your web root to be the `public` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create **.htaccess** in your root and add these lines and check.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you make a .htaccess file and write this code

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```